# Looping through list elements to replace strings in each element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, str-replace

I have a list with universities:

```
['1 1  LOMONOSOV MOSCOW STATE UNIVERSITY  XL FO VH  5  A  100 100 100  87.1            52.4 52  99.3 87  100 100', '', '', '', ''],
['2 2 NOVOSIBIRSK STATE UNIVERSITY                                                 M CO VH 98.1 96.5 88.9 98.8 59.7 38.1 69.8 92.1 99.4 96.7', '', '', '', ''],
...
```

I would like to remove superfluous information (nrs, spaces, ...) and just keep the university name.

For this I am trying to loop through my list, replacing numbers and other unwanted chars with "".

So far I have:

```
for i in range(len(flat_data2)):

    mainString = flat_data2[i]

    def replaceMultiple(mainString, unwanted, input_char):
    # Iterate over the strings to be replaced
        for elem in unwanted :
        # Check if string is in the main string
            if elem in mainString :
            # Replace the string
                mainString = mainString.replace(elem, input_char)

        return  mainString
replaceMultiple(mainString, unwanted, input_char)
```

Unfortunately, I only returned the final element of my list (though the unwanted chars are removed...).

What am I missing? Or do you have better solution?
Many thanks!

Comment: You're iterating through them and then returning just mainString.When you `#Replace the string` you can assign it to a new list to keep the parsed data. Then return the entire list.

Comment: You might want to do `flat_data2[i] = replaceMultiple(mainString, unwanted, input_char)`. Besides, it's not clear that replaceMulitple is called within your loop, so your issue might come from a missing indentation...

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. I added a `flat_data2_new = []` at the top and changed it to `flat_data2_new.append(mainString)` and `  return  flat_data2_new` but now I am returned a list with the same final element, each time with one fewer unwanted char... any idea what's missing?

Comment: @Adonis Thanks! When I indent replaceMultiple and adjust the code below accordingly, I get `unexpected indent` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you keep on defining the function every loop iteration, but you don't run it or save its output. The minimum changes to get this to work are:

```
def replaceMultiple(s, unwanted, input_char):
    # Iterate over the strings to be replaced
    for elem in unwanted:
        # Replace the string, does not do anything if `elem` not in `s`
        s = s.replace(elem, input_char)
    return s

flat_data2_new = [replaceMultiple(x) for x in flat_data2]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! After changing it to `flat_data2_new = [replaceMultiple(x, unwanted, input_char) for x in flat_data2]` it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
input_char = ""
conv = ''.maketrans({c: input_char for c in unwanted})

l = list()   # if you want a list of all your strings
for i in range(len(flat_data2)):
    mainString = flat_data2[i].translate(conv)
    l.append(mainString)
```

Comment: Better [Loop like a Native](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html): `l = [x.translate(conv) for x in flat_data2]`.

Comment: Thanks! For this I get `ValueError: string keys in translate table must be of length 1` . I did manage to replace using `maketrans` when defining `intab = "1234567890."
outtab = "           "` but then I get white spaces everywhere as in and out must be the same length. Any idea how to resolve the "must be of length 1"-issue?